# Javascript method "undefined" when it is already?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function googleJS1(){
            var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var newScript = doc.createElement('div');
            newScript.setAttribute("id", "google_translate_element");
            var bodyClass = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];         
            bodyClass.insertBefore(newScript, bodyClass.childNodes[0]);
        }

        function googleJS2(){
            var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var newScript = doc.createElement('script');
            newScript.setAttribute("src", "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit");
            var bodyClass = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
            bodyClass.insertBefore(newScript, bodyClass.childNodes[0]);
        }

        function googleJS3(){
            var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var newScript = doc.createElement('script');
            newScript.setAttribute("src", "http://www.mydomain.com/google.js");
            var bodyClass = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
            bodyClass.insertBefore(newScript, bodyClass.childNodes[1]);
        }

        function googleJS4(){
            var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var newScript = doc.createElement('style');
            var content = doc.createTextNode('.goog-te-banner-frame { display: none; } #google_translate_element {}');
            newScript.appendChild(content);
            var bodyClass = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
            bodyClass.insertBefore(newScript, bodyClass.childNodes[2]);
        }
        </script>
        <iframe width=100% height= 100% onload ="googleJS1(); googleJS2(); googleJS3(); googleJS4();" class=iframe2 src="www.mydomain.com/test.html">
```

This code works fine on another server of mine elsewhere. However whenever this is run the console says "Uncaught referencer error, method undefined". Even though it is defined, why does it throw this message and how do I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What function is it complaining about?

Comment: @JanHančič it's complaining about method googleJS1(); If I comment out onload="googleJS1()", it complains about googleJS2();

Comment: Why are you including jQuery when you are selecting items and changing attributes with vanilla js?

Comment: I included it just in case that's what's missing. So what do you think the issue is? I know that normal js shouldn't need any imports but I really can't think of a reason why this would throw all these undefined errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested, but I'm assuming this is because the `onload` event is attached to the iframe, and will therefore be called inside the iframe's scope. Try calling `window.parent.googleJS1()` instead.